# Questions about google test and assertion output (test results); can I trust when gtest says a test passed?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

When I create a `TEST` or `TEST_F` test, how can I know that my assertion is actually executing?

The problem I have is, when I have an empty `TEST_F`, for example,

```
TEST_F(myFixture, test1) {}
```

When it runs, gtest says this test passes. I would have expected the test to fail, until I write test code. Anyway.

So, my problem is that when gtest says that when test is "OK" or that it passed, I can't trust it, because a test could "pass" if there is no test code.

It would be nice to print what my `EXPECT_` or `ASSERT` calls are doing and then see that they pass. Problem is, if I do any `std::cout` calls, that seems to be out of sync with the test results at the end. The output messages are not in sync with any of my own `std::cout` calls.

Is there a verbose option to google test? How can I be sure the `EXPECT` that I coded is actually running?

Comment: I think you thinking about assertions back-to-front.  They're not "statements that are required to make the test pass", they're "statements that could cause the test to fail".  Thus I think you're basically asking "how can I ensure that each test-case executes at least one assertion?".

Comment: Also, you can ensure your tests are useful by writing them *before* the code works and watching them fail to ensure they fail for the right reason.

Comment: Yes. How can I ensure assertion execution?

Comment: Make an assertion that always fails (something like `ASSERT(false);`) and check if it says your test failed.

Comment: @mycodeplanet as above, you write a failing test, *then* make it pass. Google "test driven development".

Answer (score 0):

You might consider looking at TDD, Test Driven Development, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

- write one test => it will fail
- write code to make the test pass => test passes

Rinse and repeat: express each requirement as a test, that initially fails.  Write code to make that test pass.